# Excel: Search and Replace based on Rules

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a list in Excel more than 3000 rows that I would like to research and replace some words within the list based on another list.

For example:
List 1:
Blackcurrant Juice 500ml
Strawberry Juice 750ml

List 2:
have two columns (a: the word that I want to replace, b: the word that I want to replace with)
A: Blackcurrant should be B: B/currant
A: Strawberry should be B: Strawb

And I want search in list 1 and replace the some word based on List two

Any ideas?

Comment: I can do a Vlookup with two table and exact match but I don't know how to look a word within a cell and then replace it based on another list using Vlookups

Comment: I assigned VBA because it thought it can be done with a Macro  but I have ammended the post. List 1 is only one colume containing a brand explanation (e.g Blackcurrant Juice 500ml) but i have in another sheet two columns (it will be always two columns). column1: containing the word that I want to replace (e.g Blackcurrant) and Column2: the word that I want to replace with (e.g B/currant).

Comment: Did you perhaps see my answer? Is it perhaps not working as intended?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know what your criteria is, but, I've got enough here I hope to get you going.

Any way, my first sheet has

[image]

And my second sheet has

[image]

Then, on my first sheet, in column B I have the following code

```
=VLOOKUP(LEFT(A3,SEARCH(" ",A3)-1),Sheet2!$A$1:$B$2, 2, FALSE)
```

And a screen shot to show what column B now displays

[image]

**Update**

Update function to

```
=CONCATENATE(VLOOKUP(LEFT(A3,SEARCH(" ",A3)-1),Sheet2!$A$1:$B$2, 2, FALSE), RIGHT(A3, SEARCH(" ",A3)-1))
```

So it will display `B/currant juice 500ml`

Comment: I think it works if the word that I want to replace is at the beginning of the sentence. This is a good start but the ultimate goals is replace the word blackcurrant with the B/currant

Comment: @Pisaro Updated my post. It now displays the full string.

Answer (score 0):

Once you run the `VLOOKUP`, you can use substitute:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1, LEFT(A1, FIND(" ",A1)-1), B1, 1)
```

A1 is the cell containing `Blackcurrant Juice 500ml`, B1 is the cell containing `B/currant` after `VLOOKUP` was run.

Or you can combine both formulas as below:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1, LEFT(A1, FIND(" ",A1)-1), VLOOKUP(LEFT(A1, FIND(" ",A1)-1), Sheet2!A:B, 2, 0), 1)
```